# How to troubleshoot boto3 role assumption

Tags: python, boto3

I will preface this by saying that the trust policy shows on the UI that the role, /workdocs_api_pull, is listed in the trusted entities can assume this role section for /WorkDocs_API_Developer.  Also to note is this is cross accounts.

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/workdocs_api_pull/bin/dcgs_sds_pull.py", line 76, in lambda_handler
    get_folder_contents(aws_region)
  File "/var/task/workdocs_api_pull/bin/dcgs_sds_pull.py", line 56, in get_folder_contents
    role = assume_role(wd_role_arn, aws_region)
  File "/var/task/workdocs_api_pull/bin/dcgs_sds_pull.py", line 48, in assume_role
    RoleSessionName = 'workdocs_session'
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 272, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 576, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account_num>:assumed-role/LambdaFullAccessRole/workdocs_api_pull is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<account_num>:role/WorkDocs_API_Developer
```

Here is the code:

```
import boto3

aws_region ='us-east-1'
wd_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::<account_num>:role/WorkDocs_API_Developer'

def temp_keys():    
    session = boto3.Session()
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    keys = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

    return keys

def assume_role(wd_role_arn, aws_region):
    creds = temp_keys()

    boto_sts = boto3.client('sts',
                          aws_access_key_id=creds.access_key,
                          aws_secret_access_key=creds.secret_key,
                          aws_session_token=creds.token,
                          region_name=aws_region
                          )
    role_credentials = boto_sts.assume_role(RoleArn = wd_role_arn,
                                       RoleSessionName = 'workdocs_session'
                                       )

    return role_credentials.credentials

def lambda_handler(event, context) :  

    def get_folder_contents(aws_region):
        role = assume_role(wd_role_arn, aws_region) 
        print(role.access_key,'\n',role.secret_key,'\n',role.token)
        folder_id = '<folder_id>'
        client = boto3.client('workdocs',
                              aws_access_key_id=role.access_key,
                              aws_secret_access_key=role.secret_key,
                              aws_session_token=role.token,
                              region_name=aws_region
                              )
        folder = client.get_folder(FolderId = folder_id)
        print(folder)
        return folder

    get_folder_contents(aws_region)
```

How can I get to the bottom of why this isn't working?

Comment: The problem isn't the code, it's your IAM configurations. Contact AWS support.

Comment: This is what I thought; I don't own the account for the role I am assuming.  I am going to try creating a trust policy JSON and send it to the account owner and see if they will implement it.

Comment: The trust policy is most likely what is absent.

Comment: I would use `awscli` for testing because that will make it easier to pass the command along to the account owner for their own testing.

Comment: if the trust policy was missing, why does the UI show the entity is allowed to assume the role?  The trusted role is only for Lambda, not sure how to use awscli from lambda.

Comment: You should be able to assign the lambda roll to a regular IAM user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case was not the trust policy, but the permissions policy.  I needed to add stsAssumeRole to the permissions policy for their IAM Role in my account.